# How to avoid unwanted scale up when small image is being used with ImageView with fitCenter scaleType

Tags: android, image

I have the following `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/drink" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I had experiment with various type of `scaleType`. I can't find a good `scaleType`, which plays well for both "large" image and "small" image.

1. Retain aspect ratio
2. No cropping. All content of the image should be visible.
3. If the image height, or width is greater than `ImageView`, scale down should be performed.
4. If the image height and width is smaller than `ImageView`, original image should be displayed. **No scale up**

I had tried `fitCenter`. It plays well for 1, 2, 3. But not 4. It perform unnecessary "scale up" on small image.

### fitCenter

When large image 2432x3286 is being used.

[image]

When small image 96x96 is being used. **Unwanted scale up is being performed**

[image]

---

If I try to use `center`, it doesn't play well for 2. Large image will be cropped.

Small image is OK. No scale up will be performed.

### center

When large image 2432x3286 is being used, **unwanted cropping happen** (The straw object is not visible anymore)

[image]

Any idea how can I have a better `scaleType`?

Or, must I check the image size and compare it with `ImageView` size, to determine correct `scaleType`? I prefer not to go for that path, as my image inputs are in `Uri` form. It is cumbersome for me to determine image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 
`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

**or**

set width and height wrap_content and set max height and width for your imageview like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```